# How can I inherit all sqlalchemy functions inside a new class?

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I tried some of inharitacne combinations but do not work any of all. This is what I got finally

```
import sqlalchemy
class SentioDB(sqlalchemy):

    def __init__(self):
        #Create and engine and get the metadata
        Base = declarative_base()
        self.engine = create_engine('mysql://sentio_reader:thereader@sentiodb.cloudapp.net/sentio')
        self.engine.echo = True
        self.metadata = MetaData(bind=self.engine)
        self.metadata.reflect(bind=self.engine)
        self.create_all_tables()
        self.session = create_session(bind=self.engine)
```

This gives ;

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am missing some novice point for sure. IS there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`sqlalchemy` is a module, not a class. You shouldn't try and inherit from it.

Comment: Then is there any other method to call all its functions from my custom class definition ?

Comment: No, that's not how you use functions in Python. Import them and use them where they are.